# django: validate a modification form

Tags: django, forms, validation

I am trying to validate an update form in django. Here is my code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LawsIdsForm(request.POST)
    lawToValidate= form.data['lawsToValidate']
    #if a law is selected
    if lawToValidate!="":
        law=LawsIdsModel.objects.get(id=lawToValidate)
        formInstance = LawsIdsForm(instance=law, initial={'lawsToValidate':lawToValidate})  
        #saves the law
        if 'lawsValidationSaveButton' in request.POST:
            print "save"
            if form.is_valid():
                print "form valid"
                formInstance.save()
            else:
                print "form not valid", form.errors
```

Now I want to save the data. If I use formInstance.is_valid(), it does not work since the form is unbound. If I do form.is_valid(), it returns false due to unicity errors. How to tell django I don't want to add data but update data? (These unicity errors can happen only when adding data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!

Here is what I have changed:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    lawToValidate=request.POST.getlist('lawsToValidate')[0]
    #if a law is selected
    if lawToValidate!="":
        law=LawsIdsModel.objects.get(id=lawToValidate)      
        #saves the law
        if 'lawsValidationSaveButton' in request.POST:
            print "save"
            form = LawsIdsForm(request.POST, instance=law)
            if form.is_valid():
                print "form valid"
                form.save()
            else:
                print "form not valid", form.errors
```

Answer (score 0):

You should validate and save the same form:

```
        if formInstance.is_valid():     <-- change here!
            print "form valid"
            formInstance.save()
```

In your case `formInstance` form because is who has a binded instance.

Quoting [django Working with forms docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#processing-the-data-from-a-form)

> Processing the data from a form: Once is_valid() returns True, the
>   successfully validated form data will be in the form.cleaned_data
>   dictionary. This data will have been converted nicely into Python
>   types for you.

Comment: I tried your code but is_valid() returns false! So it means formInstance is not bounded!! Am I right? (No error displayed)

Comment: Yes the problem is solved! I have edited my first post. I had to create a form with both a request and an instance to make it work. Thanks for your help and your time ;).